# What unitary gate produces these quantum states from the computational basis?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, unitarity

Suppose that we have one-qubit unitary $U$ that maps 
$$  \left| 0 \right> \longmapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left| 0 \right> + {\frac{1+i}{2}} \left| 1\right> $$
and 
$$  \left| 1 \right> \longmapsto {\frac{1-i}{2}} \left| 0 \right> - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left| 1\right> $$
What is $U$?

Comment: the matrix whose columns are the amplitudes of the two output states

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly simply rewrite probability amplitudes of returned states as columns of a matrix:
$$
U = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1-i}{2} \\
\frac{1+i}{2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now do some algebra
$$
U = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} & -1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \mathrm{e}^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}} \\
\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

There is a quantum gate called $\mathrm{U2}$:
$$
\mathrm{U2}(\phi,\lambda)=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\mathrm{e}^{i\lambda} \\
\mathrm{e}^{i\phi} & \mathrm{e}^{i(\phi+\lambda)}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Setting $\phi=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\lambda = \frac{3}{4}\pi$ you have a resut since $\phi+\lambda =\pi$, so $\mathrm{e}^{i(\phi+\lambda)} = \mathrm{e}^{i\pi} = -1$ and $-\mathrm{e}^{i\lambda}=-\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{3}{4}\pi} = -\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$.

**Conclusion: $U=\mathrm{U2}\big(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3}{4}\pi\big)$**

Comment: I like how you started from the beginning and never skipped a step, well done!

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on the detail of *why* writing out the columns works:

Start by writing the action of the unitary:
\begin{align*}
U|0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle+\frac{1+i}{2}|1\rangle \\
U|1\rangle=\frac{1-i}{2}|0\rangle-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle
\end{align*}
Before proceeding, it's always worth checking that both sides are correctly normalised. In this case, they are.

Now take the inner product of each equation with $\langle 0|$:
$$
\langle 0|U|0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\qquad\langle 0|U|1\rangle=\frac{1-i}{2}
$$
Similarly, using $\langle 1|$, you get
$$
\langle 1|U|0\rangle=\frac{1+i}{2}\qquad\langle 1|U|1\rangle=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$
So, these identify all four matrix elements, which you can just insert:
$$
U=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1-i}{2} \\ \frac{1+i}{2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}\right).
$$
(I should say that I always get muddled between the two off-diagonal elements. So I have to stop and think about, for example, $\langle 0|U|1\rangle$, and which element is selected by doing the inner product $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\end{array}\right)U\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$: top row, right-hand column.)

Don't forget to check that your answer is reasonable by verifying $UU^\dagger=I$.